# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index out of bounds

Tags: java, arrays, character

I was getting this error while running the following code. I couldn't find out what was wrong with the code.

As far as I can see, there's some issue with my second character array. But couldn't find out what was wrong. First tried running the last loop before temp_count. Then also tried temp_count±1. Yet, I failed. I have also tried taking different array size. still no luck

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class oop2 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String str = new String();
        int temp_count = 0;

        //New input of string

        str=sc.nextLine();

        char[] c = str.toCharArray();
        char[] temp = new char[temp_count];

        //Converting uppercase to lower case for convenience

        for(int i=0; i<str.length(); i++)
        {
            if (Character.isUpperCase(c[i])) 
            {
                c[i]=(char) (c[i]+32);    
            }
        }


        //verifying whether the alphabet exists

        for(char x = 'a'; x<='z'; x++)
        {
            int count=0;
            for(int i=0; c[i]!='\0'; i++)
            {
                if (c[i]==x) 
                {
                    count++;
                }
            }


            //if the alphabet is not found, then putting the alphabet in

            if (count==0) 
            {
                temp[temp_count]=x;
                temp_count++;    
            }
        }

        
        //Verifying whether it's a pangram or not

        if (temp_count==0) 
        {
            System.out.println("Pangram");    
        }
        else
        {
            //if not pangram then this part will execute
            System.out.println("Not Pangram");
            System.out.printf("Missing Characters: ");

            //printing out the missing character
            for(int i=0; i<temp_count-1; i++)
            {
                System.out.print(temp[i]+", ");
            }
        }
        sc.close();
    }    
}
```

Comment: This statement: `char[] temp = new char[temp_count];` creates a `char` array of length `temp_count`.  `temp_count` is set to 0 in  your code ( a few lines up ) so the result is a zero-length array.  Later you `temp[temp_count]=x;` which would fail in any case of the current value of `temp_count`.  If you have the java debugger available, I strongly recommend learning its use.

Answer (score 0):

```
    import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String str = new String();
        int temp_count = 0;
        //New input of string
        str = sc.nextLine();
        char[] c = str.toCharArray();
        char[] temp = new char[0];
        //Converting uppercase to lower case for convenience
        for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
            if (Character.isUpperCase(c[i])) {
                c[i] = (char)(c[i] + 32);
            }
        }
        //verifying whether the alphabet exists
        for (char x = 'a'; x <= 'z'; x++) {
            int count = 0;
            for (int i = 0; c[i] != '\0'; i++) {
                if (c[i] == x) {
                    count++;
                }
            }
            //if the alphabet is not found, then putting the alphabet in
            if (count == 0) {
                char [] copy = new char[temp.length+1];
                for (int i = 0; i < temp.length; i++) {
                    copy[i]=temp[i];
                }
                copy[copy.length-1] = x;
                temp=copy;
            }
        }
        //Verifying whether it's a pangram or not
        if (temp_count == 0) {
            System.out.println("Pangram");
        } else {
            //if not pangram then this part will execute
            System.out.println("Not Pangram");
            System.out.printf("Missing Characters: ");

            //printing out the missing character
            for (int i = 0; i < temp_count - 1; i++) {
                System.out.print(temp[i] + ", ");
            }
        }
        sc.close();
    }
}

Blockquote
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: this one shows the same issue